# Bad behavior of Block function

Tags: scoping

It seems that there is an extreme bug in the Block function that has puzzled me a lot today.
Below I give two code samples. In the first one can see a bug. In the second one can see that this bug is not even consistent...

```
r = kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.};
rb := kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.};
r - rb
Block[{kx = 1.}, r]
Block[{kx = 1.}, rb]
r - rb
```

The output is
0 (as should)
4 (as should)
2 (as shouldn't)
0 (as should)

Now it seems that Block somehow delays replacing kx by 2 in result line 3 and instead puts kx as 1 first.

One might try to argue that this is a feature or the usual blabla. However, This behavior is not consistent. Take for instance the following only very slightly altered code:

```
r = kx /. {kx -> 2.};
rb := kx /. {kx -> 2.};
r - rb
Block[{kx = 1.}, r]
Block[{kx = 1.}, rb]
r - rb
```

The output is
0 (as should)
2 (as should)
2 (as should)
0 (as should)

It seems that therefore the Block function has a very strange bug. For reference I am using version 12.0.0.0 in 64bit version.

Does anyone have any insights on how to avoid this bug or have a clear reason for why this happens? I was stumped for 3 hours with code that had strange behavior until I was able to break it down to this issue.

Comment: Note that this can get even funkier if you replace the Block function by a summation (iteration here is based on the Block function so there is an issue here).

    r = kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.};
    rb := kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.};
    r - rb
    Sum[r, {kx, 1, 10}]
    Sum[rb, {kx, 1, 10}]

Gives results 40 and 386?

Comment: In `rb`, `kx^2` evaluates to `1.` and then {1. -> 2.} replaces this value with `2.`. In your second example the same thing happens. I think everything is consistent.

Comment: Everything is working consistently, although it may appear confusing. Take a look at `Trace@Block[{kx = 1.}, rb]` to see what's happening under the hood in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Chip. I'm not sure what you think the bug is. Use `Trace` on `Block[{kx = 1}, rb]` to see what it's doing and why it makes sense.

Comment: Since you claim this is not a bug. Ok but at the very least it is extremely bad behavior of a function.  It certainly makes Mathematica much less reliable for me given that the Sum function is also impacted and this can also lead to issues with function definitions

Comment: @Michael "extremely bad behavior of a function", "less reliable" - not doing what *you* expect from it does not make it wrong though. I assume that your example was a minimal reduction of what you are actually trying to do, which seems a corner case to me. Perhaps you could expand on the situation in which this came up; there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: The issue is not finding a way around it. The issue is convenience of coding and how much you can trust results if some small change can throw results off by this much. Replacing bock by With or the slower module to avoid bugs caused by such dumb behaviour seems ok. But for sum and other block based stuff there seems to be no way to make it not use block. It would be good if there was an option. Again the issue is can I trust my code ever again not can I work around it.

Comment: These examples all indicate the evaluation sequence is working exactly as designed. And it is by no means clear from them what aspect of this design is being claimed as either incorrect or undesirable.It might make sense (as @MarcoB noted) to provide the actual computation of interest along with a clear indication of the expected vs actual result. (Probably best to do in a new post-- this one should be closed.)

Answer (score 10):

**This is not a bug.**

Dynamic scoping via `Block`, Lexical scoping via `Module`, and Macro replacement via `With` are sometimes confusing. All have legacies in other programming languages. Having all three in one language is powerful and expressive, but...

Let the variable `a` contain everything of interest use `SetDelayed` to give it a "value":

```
a := {kx, r, rb, s, sb}
r = kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.}; 
s = kx /. kx -> 2.;
a
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., sb} *)

rb := kx^2 /. {kx -> 2.}; 
sb := kx /. kx -> 2.
a
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., 2.} *)

r - rb
(* 0. *)
```

`Block` effectively saves the original value of `kx`, uses `kx` as $1$ everywhere during the execution of the `Block`, then restores `kx`. So-called dynamic scoping. So `rb2` and `sb` both go to $2$ via `SetDelayed`.

```
Block[{kx = 1.}, a]
(* {1., 4., 2., 2., 2.} *)

a
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., 2.} *)
```

`Module` effectively creates a new variable called (say) `kx9857373`, initializes it to 1, and uses it in place of `kx` everywhere `kx` explicitly appears in the `Module`. The global `kx` is not affected.

```
Module[{kx = 1.}, a]
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., 2.} *)

a
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., 2.} *)
```

`With` immediately replaces `kx` by 1 (like a text editor would) everywhere `kx` appears explicitly in the `With` body. But it does not appear explicitly.

```
With[{kx = 1.}, a]
(* {kx, 4., 4., 2., 2.} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `Block`, imo, or really even scoping.

The problem is that in `kx^2 /. kx -> 2.`, it seems to be assumed that `kx^2` and `kx` are different. That's not true always (e.g. if `kx` is set equal to `0`, `0.`, `1`, `1.`, `1. + 0. I`,...) and so seems a programmer error.
In general, code of the form

```
f[x] /. x -> a
```

is inherently ***buggy***, unless the programmer wants `f[x]` to be replaced by `a` instead of `f[a]`, when `f[x]` and `x` are identical.  That seems unlikely.

The issue of `rb` evaluating to `2.` is not a scoping issue, because the evaluation to `2.` is going to occur whether `kx = 1.` is set inside or outside `Block`. The problem is how to code the replacement operation if the pattern is going to be a global variable.

It's nice to have the MWE provided by the OP, but it's contrived in a way that makes it hard to figure a good suggestion for an actual use-case.  Despite the OP's statement that "The issue is not finding a way around it," I think it becomes an issue in light of the preceding analysis.

*First approach.*
Don't use `expr /. x -> a` if `x` is a symbol that sometimes will be given a value.  There is probably a better way to perform the computation anyway; ask on this site, if you cannot figure it out.  Maybe sometimes you have to do it, but you have to think carefully.  Later, if someone has to use your code or you reuse your code, one might forget to think through the problems and cause a bug.

*Second approach.*
Maybe one of these does what is desired:

```
kx^2 /. kx /; ! ValueQ[kx] -> 2.
kx^2 /. x_Symbol /; MatchQ[x, Unevaluated@kx] -> 2.
kx^2 /. x_Symbol /; Block[{kx}, MatchQ[x, kx]] -> 2.
kx^2 /. x_Symbol /; MatchQ[Hold@x, Hold@kx] -> 2.
Block[{kx = 2.}, #] &[kx^2];
```

Or define a function to substitute the default:

```
ClearAll[kxSub];
kxSub[expr_] /; ValueQ[kx] := expr;
kxSub[expr_] := expr /. kx -> 2.;

Block[{kx = 1},
 kx^2 // kxSub
 ]
(*  1  *)
```